# How to plot non contiguous data in xlwings chart?

Tags: charts, xlwings

In xlwings, how can I plot a xyscattered line chart, while x and y axis are not in contiguous columns or row (could not use range for source data)? For example x data is in column A, while y data is at column D.  Any idea?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/api.html#chart), the Chart API is not very mature right now. So what you want is currently not implemented yet. You can, however, access the underlying COM ojbect (on Windows) or appscript object (on Mac) by using `chart.xl_chart` (assuming, `chart` is your xlwings chart object) and then directly manipulate that underlying object to achieve what you want.